# How can i make my program do a specific calculation in a sequential IF statement

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char ticketType;
   int totalBill, studAmount, ticketType_R= 6500, ticketType_G= 7500;

   printf("\nEnter your ticket type: ");
   scanf("%c", &ticketType);
   printf("\nEnter amount of students: ");
   scanf("%d", &studAmount);


   if(ticketType==ticketType_R)
   {
       totalBill==studAmount*6500;
       printf("\nYour ticket type is R and your total bill is: %d", ticketType_R, totalBill);
   }


   if (ticketType==ticketType_G)
   {
       totalBill==studAmount*7500;
       printf("\nYour ticket type is G and your total bill is: %d", ticketType_G, totalBill);
   }

   printf("\nThe amount of students attending are: %d ", studAmount);

   return 0;
}
```

I tried the code that I made above and I was expecting it to

1. the type of ticket the user choose
2. print the amount of students attending
3. calculate the total amount by multiplying the amount of students by the price for the ticket
4. print the total amount

Comment: Neither of the if conditions in your posted code will be true. You read a single char to the variable ticketType. You then compare that value to 6500 and then 7500. Max char on most platforms is either 127 or 255. As a guess, perhaps you want to compare against 'R' or 'G'?

Comment: You have tagged this with C++ but are using `printf` and `scanf` which are superseded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I believe you want to calculate value according to ticket type and the number of students.

That's how we can do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char ticketType;
   int totalBill, studAmount, ticketType_R= 6500, ticketType_G= 7500;

    printf("Enter the ticket type (R/G): "); // Input ticket type
    scanf("%c", &ticketType);

    // Use of Sequential if-else statement to calculate the total bill
    if (ticketType == 'R')
    {
        printf("Enter the number of students: ");
        scanf("%d", &studAmount);
        totalBill = ticketType_R * studAmount;
        printf("Your ticket type is R and your total bill is: %d", totalBill);
    }
    else if (ticketType == 'G')
    {
        printf("Enter the number of students: ");
        scanf("%d", &studAmount);
        totalBill = ticketType_G * studAmount;
        printf("Your ticket type is G and your total bill is: %d", totalBill);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid ticket type");
    }

    // Total Students 
    printf("\nTotal number of students: %d", studAmount);

    return 0;
}
```

As you are interested to do it in Python, that's how you will do it.

```
ticket_type = input("Enter the ticket type (R/G): ")
stud_amount = int(input("Enter the number of students: "))


if ticket_type == "R":
    total_bill = 6500 * stud_amount
    print("Your ticket type is R and your total bill is: ", total_bill)
elif ticket_type == "G":
    total_bill = 7500 * stud_amount
    print("Your ticket type is G and your total bill is: ", total_bill)
else:
    print("Invalid ticket type")

print("Your Total number of students: ", stud_amount)
```

Comment: thanks, I'm very new to this programming thing, how would write the python equivalent?

Comment: Check the Updated answer for Python,

Comment: thank you so much, may I ask what's the best way to learn to code?

Comment: Watch good tutorials, read books and docs and Practice.